# Selenium wait visibility_of_all_elements_located times out

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriverwait

I'm testing how to get all the results in a search results page to learn how to use Selenium. When logged into the site, I can see full source for this specific page in just a normal browser, including the div for a line which finishes the page.

With a longer results set of course, normal browser won't show, as Javascript loaded lazily, so I looked to find a way for Selenium to wait until all the results loaded.

I based below on wait code at: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Following throws timeout error for this specific page:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3t0c")))

finally:
    print('done with webdriver wait anyway')
```

Error thrown is:

```
in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3t0c")))
  File "..longFilePath....\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

with nothing showing after `Message:`

EDIT:
Below error is different one due to missing brackets as pointed out below @QHarr thanks:

```
in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.CLASS_NAME, "_3t0c"))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

NB if I comment out this try loop, I can still get all the results on this page.

Otherwise, I tried getting Selenium to wait for the end of results div class, also timeout error at timeout = 100, I can see page loading in probably less than 20 seconds in Selenium.

But I just tried with different  class= "_32mo", which also seems to have one per name in the list, and this apparently does not time out.

I'm new to Selenium and indeed newish to web-scraping, I'm just curious, can anyone explain what might be going on?

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. Use the API. And if you can't do it in the API don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

For the error shown the method expects a tuple so you need more brackets. Try

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3t0c")))
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeError:takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

assign type and value of locator into variable
for e.g :
a =(By.CLASS_NAME, "_3t0c")

and then pass this variable into bracket
for e.g :

```
a = (By.CLASS_NAME, "_3t0c")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(a))
```